# Opal is completely broken?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, opalrb, opal

I've been totally unsuccessful in getting Opal to work.

When I try to embed it in a Sinatra server using the tutorial [here](http://opalrb.org/docs/sinatra/) or the example code [here](https://github.com/opal/opal/tree/master/examples), I get `undefined method 'source_maps' for #<Opal::Server:0x8b11540>`. When I use the updated code linked at the bottom of [this post](https://github.com/opal/opal/issues/716), I get `uninitialized constant Opal::Sprockets::SourceMapHeaderPatch`.

So, I abandon Sinatra and try using Opal in a Rack app instead, using their own example [here](https://github.com/opal/opal/tree/master/examples). And I get a totally blank webpage.

Finally, I follow the tutorial [here](http://opalrb.org/docs/using_sprockets/) ***to the letter***, and again all I get is a blank page in my browser.

So, what am I doing wrong? Or is Opal really as broken as it appears?

(oh, and that's not even mentioning the two serious out-of-bounds bugs in the `rescue` block in `parse()` in `opal/parser.rb` that completely kill any chance of debugging an error)

Comment: Can you share your code with us? So we can check it. I have most experience with running it Rails but might be able to help

Comment: I think part of your problem might be that you're trying to use source maps... they've been acting kind of funky in recent versions. Also, as @gabrielrios said, it would be good to share some code so that we can determine exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation needs to be updated and versioned.

But 0.8 rc1 seems pretty stable and has working examples [here](https://github.com/opal/opal/tree/0-8-stable/examples) (including source maps).

Keep in mind that source maps are kinda hacked into sprockets and the rack setup to get them working isn't trivial.